# How to return the current and previous value of the mouse coordinate?

Tags: javascript

On the below code, `onmousemove` is checking the coordinate X and Y of the mouse travelling. And then I return inside `myInterval` the coordinate X and Y at the end of 1 second. My intention is to know where the customer's mouse is every second.

```
let latestX;
let latestY;

let previousX;
let previousY;  

let mouseHasMoved = false;
DEFAULT_INTERVAL = 2000;

onmousemove = () => {
    window.addEventListener('mousemove', (e)=> {
        latestX = e.x
        latestY = e.y
        mouseHasMoved = true;
    });
};


myInterval = setInterval(()=> {
    if (mouseHasMoved) {
        mouseHasMoved = false;
        console.log(`x: ${latestX}, y: ${latestY}`)
    }
}, DEFAULT_INTERVAL);
```

I want to expand the above code to also show me the previous coordinate, using `previousX` and `previousY`.

Let's say my current coordinates are X: 10 and Y: 20.

So, initially `previousX` and `previousY` would be undefined and latestX: 10 and latestY: 20. After I change my mouse coordinate; X: 10 and Y: 20 would be assigned to `previousX` and `previousY`, and `latestX` and `latestY` would have new values.

I have tried assigning the values as below, but it didn't work. Both previous and latest had the same values:

```
onmousemove = () => {
    window.addEventListener('mousemove', (e)=> {
        previousX = latestX;
        previousY = latestY;
        
        latestX = e.x
        latestY = e.y
        mouseHasMoved = true;
    });
};
```

Comment: You can use [`MouseEvent.movementX`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent/movementX) and [`MouseEvent.movementY`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent/movementY) to calculate the previous coordinates.

Comment: This wouldn't work, because I want to return values every second only. So previous distances would not be accurate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you assign the `previousX` and `previousY` values in the mouse move handler. If you move this to the interval handler, it will work as expected:

```js
let latestX;
let latestY;

let previousX;
let previousY;  

let mouseHasMoved = false;
DEFAULT_INTERVAL = 2000;

myInterval = setInterval(()=> {
    if (mouseHasMoved) {
        mouseHasMoved = false;
        console.log(`prevX: ${previousX}, prevY: ${previousY}, x: ${latestX}, y: ${latestY}`);
        previousX = latestX;
        previousY = latestY;
    }
}, DEFAULT_INTERVAL);

onmousemove = () => {
    window.addEventListener('mousemove', (e)=> {
        latestX = e.x
        latestY = e.y
        mouseHasMoved = true;
    });
};
```

Comment: Thank you! That has indeed worked as I intended